# Oracle; limit rows per column value

Tags: oracle, triggers, duplicates, row

I have a table with a postal code column (Dutch format, but never mind that)

```
CREATE TABLE  "TEST"
(
    "ID" NUMBER(10) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "POSTALCODE" VARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    ....
    CONSTRAINT "TEST_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE
)
```

I'm trying to create a trigger that limits the number of records with duplicate postal codes; only two rows may contain the same postal code at once.
I tried the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_TEST_PC
    BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT OF "POSTALCODE " ON "TEST"
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN ( OLD.POSTALCODE <> NEW.POSTALCODE )
DECLARE
   v_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO v_count
    FROM TEST
    WHERE POSTALCODE = :NEW.POSTALCODE ;  
    IF (v_count > 2) THEN
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'Max. 2 rows with same postal code.');
    END IF;
END TR_TEST_PC;
```

But this returns an error:

```
ORA-04091: table MYDB.TEST is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "MYDB.TR_TEST_PC", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'MYDB.TR_TEST_PC'
```

I understand this is because you can't access a table you're mutating.

How can I make a trigger that ensure no more than 2 records contain the same postal code?

Comment: Is there a relationship between the two rows - is one always 'active' and one 'inactive', for example? Just thinking that if you had another column that only allowed one of two values, you could add a unique index over that field and the post code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using an after-update trigger instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_TEST_PC
    AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT OF "POSTALCODE" ON "TEST"
DECLARE
    v_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(COUNT(*))
    INTO v_count
    FROM TEST
    GROUP BY POSTALCODE;
    IF (v_count > 2) THEN
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'Max. 2 rows with same postal code.');
    END IF;
END TR_TEST_PC;
```

Answer (score 1):

This may work instead of your trigger:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_my
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT AS
SELECT POSTALCODE, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM TEST GROUP BY POSTALCODE
/

ALTER TABLE mv_my ADD CHECK(cnt < 2)
/
```

Let me know.
Cheers,

Sebas