# Trigger does not allow any inserts

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have written a trigger that does not allow more than two 'Full' ranked professors as part of the faculty (For example, trigger should fire if a new (third) Full professor is added or rank is updated to Full for one of the existing Associate professors.)

It does compile but does not let me know add any data to my table at all. It only needs to be used once. Do I use the statement level trigger for this?
Also, at the moment it does not let me update or insert Professor Rank at all, whether its Full or Associate. How would I fix that?

I have also been told that before/after and that my logic of comparison is wrong. Please help!

Here is the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_PROF_RANK
after insert or update of F_RANK
on FACULTY

DECLARE
FULL_RANK_COUNT integer;
MAX_FULL_RANK_COUNT number :=2;

begin 
select count(*) into FULL_RANK_COUNT
from FACULTY 
where F_RANK ='Full';

if FULL_RANK_COUNT < MAX_FULL_RANK_COUNT
then 
return;
else 

if (FULL_RANK_COUNT >= MAX_FULL_RANK_COUNT) then
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20000, 'Can only have 2 professors with ranking "Full".');
end if;
end if;
end;
/
```

I test it with the following statement:

```
insert into FACULTY values(6, 'John', 'Bonny', 'M', 13, '4079347153', 'Associate', 80000, 2, 6034, Null);
```

But it doesn't allow me to insert any records into the table. And this is the error that I get:

```
Error starting at line : 240 in command -
insert into FACULTY values(6, 'John', 'Bonny', 'M', 13, '4079347153', 'Associate', 80000, 2, 6034, Null)
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-20000: Can only have 2 professors with ranking "Full".
ORA-06512: at "IT337104.TRG_PROF_RANK", line 16
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'IT337104.TRG_PROF_RANK'
20000. 00000 -  "%s"
*Cause:    The stored procedure 'raise_application_error'
           was called which causes this error to be generated.
*Action:   Correct the problem as described in the error message or contact
           the application administrator or DBA for more information.
```

please help, I just to make sure I can insert data.

Thank you

Comment: You have `>=` where I think you need `>`.  Also, you may already have 2 or more full ranked professors in the table; the condition fires even if the inserted professor is not full ranked. You may want a 'referencing new as' clause (or equivalent in Oracle SQL) and to check whether the newly inserted record is a 'full' professor.  A change from Full to Associate should always be OK (according to this trigger — another trigger might insist there's always at least one full professor, though that's probably over-zealous).

Answer (score 0):

The query should raise a mutating table error so the trigger shouldn't be executing at all. You cannot query a table from within a trigger written on that table. You must either maintain the count of full professorships elsewhere or perform the test in your application code before issuing the insert or update. This is a problem with any data integrity check that depends on data in other rows of the same table, other than, of course, a UNIQUE constraint. It simply can't be done from within a trigger on that table.

But even if you could, you have a major logic error. If your table already contains two full professors, this trigger would prevent *all* Inserts and Updates on the table, even if they did not involve full professors.

But all is not lost. If you fix the logic flaw, turn the trigger into a `before` trigger for each row, examine the contents of `:new.F_RANK` and act accordingly, one solution you may want to look into can be found here: [Oracle; limit rows per column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20766378/oracle-limit-rows-per-column-value). (The second answer with the materialized view, not the first.)